# How to iterate and return each resulting array values inside of a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, iteration

The bellow function stores the desire values in the 'result' array. But when I am trying to iterate that result array and returning the values, It only gives the first value of the index[0]. How can I acquire all the values by iterating the array and by returning it?
[N.B. console.log() works perfectly.]

```
function alphabetPosition(text) {
    var alphabet = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];
    
    var stringToArray = text.split('');
    var result = [];

    for(var i = 0; i <= stringToArray.length-1; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j <= alphabet.length; j++){
            if(alphabet[j] == stringToArray[i].toLowerCase()){
                result.push(alphabet.indexOf(alphabet[j])+1);
            }
        } 
        
    }
    for(var i = 0; i <= result.length; i++){
        return result[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: You can return only once from a function, return `result` to get all the values, and iterate the array where ever you need it.  Or return the results as a string: `return result.join('');`.

Comment: You can only return once unless you use a [generator function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*)

Comment: Ohh I got that. That loop is trying to give multiple inputs but as it returns only once that why it's not giving the rest of the value. But can I possibly acquire all those values?

Comment: Can you provide an input string, and your expected output because there maybe a simpler way of writing that.

Comment: All you need inside your function is `return text.split('').map(c => c.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 0x60)`

Comment: @ChrisG So, basically doable as a one-liner? `const alphabetPosition = text => text.split('').map(c => c.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 0x60)`

Comment: @JeremyThille Yeah, but I don't like declaring functions like that :)

Comment: I can't resist a one-liner

Comment: @JeremyThille I can, knowing that using `function` I can call it "before" declaring it :)

Comment: @ChrisG whats the reason for `0x60` if you can just write `96`

Comment: @Reyno `96` is a random number, `0x60` kind of implies why you have to do that in the first place

Comment: @ChrisG The purpose of my function is, you are required to, given a string, replace every letter with its position in the alphabet.
If anything in the text isn't a letter, ignore it and don't return it.
"a" = 1, "b" = 2, etc.

Example
alphabetPosition("The sunset sets at twelve o' clock.")
Should return "20 8 5 19 21 14 19 5 20 19 5 20 19 1 20 20 23 5 12 22 5 15 3 12 15 3 11" (as a string). But using return text.split('').map(c => c.toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0) - 0x60) will also give spaces and other characters as you have used charCodeAt(). Any solution for this?

Comment: Sure, filter and join the Array: `.filter(c => c >=1 && c <= 26).join(" ")`

Comment: @ChrisG That's a lovely piece of code. I am used to coding on old-fashioned es5 when it comes to js. May I know where can I learn beautiful codes like this other than MDN?

Comment: "other than MDN"? How about MDN? Also, Array.map for instance works in IE9, I don't exactly think it's a brand new ES6 feature.